spark sql query result issue
I have 2 spark dataset views
dataset dept - ds1_view has 371815 records
dept dataset has multiple rows with same userid
dataset user - ds2_view has 27217 records with unique userid
i need to combine all cols from both view
but not getting expected result
can any body let me know where i am doing wrong
i tried this sql query
select * from ds1_view v1, ds2_view v2 where v1.userid=v2.userid
it gives result of 35565075 rows
while expected result should be
371815 records

Welcome to SO! Your SQL query looks good to me. Could you please check if ds2_view probably does contain a few duplicates? select userid, count(*) from ds2_view group by userid having count(*) > 1

Hi werner, as i mentioned above ds1_view has multiple rows with same userid but ds2_view has unique userid

You could try to reproduce the problem with a small dataset that you could post here

the query is working fine if i use natural join
